# common values b/w fields

Tags: mysql, sql, join

This table lists user and item id's

```
user_id         item_id
1                1
1                2
1                3
2                1
2                3
3                1
3                4
3                3
```

How can I run a query on this table to list all the items that are common between  given users.

My guess is, this will need a self join, but I'm not sure.

i am trying this quering but it's returning an error

```
SELECT *
FROM recs 1
JOIN recs 2 ON 2.user_id='2' AND 2.item_id=1.item_id
WHERE 1.user_id='1'
```

Comment: It helps if you also include the error you're getting in the question. :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using alias names that start in a letter:

```
SELECT *
FROM recs r1
JOIN recs r2 ON r2.user_id='2' AND r2.item_id=r1.item_id
WHERE r1.user_id='1'
```

This returns

```
user_id  item_id
-------  -------
      1        1
      1        3
```

for your data. [Demo on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b482/1).

Note: I kept single quotes in the query, because I assume that both IDs in your table are of character type. If that is not the case, remove single quotes around user ID values `'1'` and `'2'`.

> I want it for n number of users ... a I want the query to return all item_id's that are common among the users

```
SELECT DISTINCT(r1.item_id)
FROM recs r1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM recs r2
  WHERE r2.item_id=r1.item_id
  AND r1.user_id <> r2.user_id
)
```

[Demo #2.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b482/6)

Comment: Thanks a lot ... but i want it for n number of users ... a i want the query to return all item_id's that are common b/w the users

Comment: the query i used 
SELECT DISTINCT(r1.item_id)
FROM recs r1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM recs r2
  WHERE r2.item_id=r1.item_id
  AND r1.user_id != r2.user_id
  and r2.item_id!='1'
)